How can I setup my template file so main pipeline will call properly
I have a main pipeline and a template file. The main pipeline calls the template. The template has 2 jobs that passes a variable from one job to the other. If I have this in just the main pipeline file without the template file, it successfully passes the variable from job to job.
However, when I try to move this code to a template file I'm getting an error about an Unexpected job
main pipeline azure-pipelines.yml
#test

trigger: none


pr: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: main
    type: git
    ref: main
    name: "Pipeline Practice 2"

  - repository: beta
    type: git
    ref: beta
    name: "Pipeline Practice 2"
    
steps:
  - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - template: aaaaa.yml@beta
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - template: aaaaa.yml@main

template aaaaa.yml
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      $someValue = "hello world"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someName;isOutput=true;]$someValue"
    name: rstest

- job: B
  dependsOn: [A]
  variables: 
    varX: $[dependencies.A.outputs['rstest.someName']]
  steps:
  - powershell: |    
      "$(varX)"
    name: rstest2



You are reusing job in your template. Change steps: to jobs: in your main pipeline azure-pipelines.yml. See more info from Template usage reference.
jobs:
  - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - template: aaaaa.yml@beta
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - template: aaaaa.yml@main

